# clang analyzer memory leaks

Tags: linux, clang, static-analysis

Why doesn't clang/clang-analyzer catch that I forgot to free `a` and have a memory leak? It's obvious. I looked at the man pages and i'm not sure what flags are required.

```
$ scan-build clang++ -std=c++11 a.cpp
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang' for static analysis
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2013-10-02-2' because it contains no reports.
$ cat ./a.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main() {
        int *a = new int;
        *a = 8;
        std::cout<< a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Statically detecting memory leaks is an unsolvable problem (which is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). You forgot the `-Wall` argument to `clang++`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: according to another user if I use malloc instead of new the analyzer picks it up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149239/c-clang-analyzer-memory-leaks

Comment: If testing at runtime you want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: BTW, I meant statically detecting reliably *all* memory leaks (which *is* unsolvable).