# C++/clang analyzer memory leaks?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, static-analysis

I'm trying to get clang++ to tell me there is a memory leak. I tried scan-build but it reported nothing. How do I get llvm/clang to warn me of this problem?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        int *a = new int;
        *a = 8;
        std::cout<< a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Memory allocated with malloc is reported for me, but not if I use `new`. E.g.: `int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: Possibly dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455157/example-code-to-trigger-clangs-static-analyser

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang analyzer memory leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149002/clang-analyzer-memory-leaks)

Answer (score 0):

False-positive pruning usually leads to removing all leaks that originate from main(), since the program will exit anyway.  Try analyzing the same code, but in a different function.

Comment: Leaking pointer allocated with new in a non `main` function is not reported for me either. There is [unix.Malloc check](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html) I can't find anything related to `new` check. Static analysis just doesn't cover everything. The reason why dynamic analysis with dtrace or other tools exists.

Answer (score 0):

Because int is too small, there is something like one "reserved section" for program so for small object no need to extend memory area, try to apply 1024 * 1024 * 10 then check the result